# In logstash/ElasticSearch/Kibana, how do I augment records following a particular stateful request?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

My application supports a lot of config, and therefore many versions of the following use case:

1. GET example.com/user/<id>
2. POST example.com/user/beta?enabled=1
3. GET example.com/user/<id>
4. POST example.com/user/beta?enabled=0
5. GET example.com/user/<id>

In my logstash/ElasticSearch/Kibana log stack, I want to be able to distinguish request #3 from requests #1 and #5, without adding per-log line output which specifies beta_enabled status.

Is it possible to append a "beta_enabled" key to my document at index time, or some other time?

Comment: Logstash can't do this out of the box. You'd have to write a custom plugin to keep per-client state information.